# Where can I get the file l1eq_pd.m?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, sampling, dft

To recover the original signal when compressive sensing is used, we get an error, to avoid the error, we need to modify the l1eq_pd.m file. How to go about it? Where can I get this file in Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

First hit on Google seems to be a reasonable start: https://github.com/gpeyre/matlab-toolboxes/blob/master/toolbox_sparsity/toolbox/l1eq_pd.m